# Failed prop type: Invalid prop openIcon supplied to CardHeader, expected a ReactNode

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to use Material-UI and create a CardHeader with custom open and close icons (openIcon, closeIcon).  I have tried sever different approaches to create the custom icons.  However I keep getting the error: `Failed prop type: Invalid prop openIcon supplied to CardHeader, expected a ReactNode`.  I have been searching for documentation identifying how to define openIcon and closeIcon however i have not been able to find anything.  I have tried SvgIcon, FontIcon and both produce the same error.  I have have seen the information on the Card [here](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/card). however it only specifies "node" with no examples or further definitions.  Could someone point me in the right direction as to where this is documented.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to figure out how to specify the openIcon and closeIcon attributes to the CardHeader

```
openIcon={<FontIcon className="material-icons">mode_edit</FontIcon>}
```

I found the answer when looking at how they specified the icon in the Avatar example.